# NFC/RFID tagging to trigger music on/off when objects enter/exit area?

Tags: audio, nfc, midi, rfid

I'm working on a sound installation for a college project in which a selection of objects can be placed in a basin with each one triggering a sound on entry, so the sounds accumulate with more objects allowing users to make their own 'mix'

I figured RFID tagging would probably be the best way to go for this, so a reader at the bottom of the basin senses nearby objects. The main problem I have is that I don't know how to trigger multiple tags at the same time with one reader.

I planned to use a raspberry pi to power an NFC reader, connected to a midi shield that would separate the value of each tag into different midi channels?

Was just wondering whether this was an appropriate route to go down, and if anyone has any other ideas? I don't Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated, the technical aspects of this project are really very new to me, and I'm not sure where to begin.

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think that SO is the right forum for this question. If you intend to use an NFC reader, what size would the basin have? How big would the objects be? Keep in mind that NFC is designed for very short distances (a few centimeters at most) and increasing the range is not as simple as using a bigger antenna.